# Storyboard won't open in Visual Studio (Xamarin). The designer could not be initialized

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

We use Visual Studio (Xamarin) to develop our Apps for Apple. Since I installed the latest update, the Storyboard wont open in Visual Studio.

I tried downgrading to the last version but that doesn't seem to work. Rebuilded, Restartet and Unloaded the project already.

Error Message:

```
MonoTouch.Design.Client.CouldNotInitializeRendererException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.CouldNotInitializeRendererException' was thrown.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 232
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 243
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
...
...
...
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.7] INFO: [2019-10-11 15:43:30.6] INFO: Waiting for renderer to start... 300
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO: [2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] ERROR: Could not initialize renderer
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO: MonoTouch.Design.Client.CouldNotInitializeRendererException: The renderer never started, bailing out... ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.RetryConnectionException ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in <118907f5eb5f4e538f3e3bdd8361378f>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at Mono.Unix.UnixClient.Connect (Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint remoteEndPoint) [0x00006] in <47e71035f6774c5fa65560f4ab0cc60e>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Unix.UnixClient.Connect(Mono.Unix.UnixEndPoint)
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.SendRequestImpl (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request) [0x0000d] in <75e4a400d63a46619c2379952ad9ffcc>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.SendRequestImpl (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request) [0x0001b] in <75e4a400d63a46619c2379952ad9ffcc>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00050] in <3fb2608a4c644b7faeb25f7a26ae637f>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequestCore (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest request, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000c2] in <3fb2608a4c644b7faeb25f7a26ae637f>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest req, System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x00000] in <3fb2608a4c644b7faeb25f7a26ae637f>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO:   at CSProxyHost.MainClass.HandleMessage (MonoTouch.Design.CommandRequest message) [0x0015b] in <22267ef404cb4303b2debccd373e2a94>:0 
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] INFO: Reloading: Server rendering completed in 61335ms
[2019-10-11 15:43:30.9] ERROR: EnsureSession (counter 1): System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.CouldNotInitializeRendererException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.CouldNotInitializeRendererException' was thrown.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 232
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 243
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) MonoTouch.Design.Client.CouldNotInitializeRendererException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.CouldNotInitializeRendererException' was thrown.
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest(CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 232
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.SendRequest[TResponse](CommandRequest req, Boolean throwIfNotRunning) in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 243
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.CreateSession() in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 111
   at MonoTouch.Design.Client.ServerProcessConnection.<CreateSessionAsync>b__28_0() in E:\A\_work\1898\s\Xamarin.Designer.iOS\MonoTouch.Design.Client\Connection\ServerProcessConnection.cs:line 116
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
```

Comment: If you are on macOS I would advise you to use the Xcode Interface Builder instead of Visual Studio, you can open it by right click on your storyboard file and then, "open with" and "Xcode Interface Builder"

Comment: @roachoverflow i have using Vs on windows. this issue is occurred sometimes. VS 2019 used with latest version 16.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Report the bug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2019) as the Storyboard should open with Visual Studio. In the mean time, you can right click on the file inside you Visual Studio For Mac and open it with "[Xcode Interface Builder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/designer/introduction?tabs=macos#revert-to-xcode)".

Comment: That solved it. Thanks. Didn't think about that. Also, I updateted everything (VS on Windows, VS on Mac and xCode on mac) to the newest version and now it works again. Don't know what went wrong the first time.

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a similar issue when I tried to open the Main.Storyboard in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.0.3.  I researched this as it has to work since I already invested in a second hand Mac Book Pro.

In my searches to find a solution, I saw a posting that said you need at least Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3 and above.  I went to Help About in Visual Studio 2019 and there was an update to Visual Studio 19 version: 16.5.4 that I now have installed.

My Mac was at Catalina 10.15.3, so I also updated my Mac Book Pro to Catalina 10.15.4 (Apple icon and select About This Mac to update Catalina).  XCode that I had installed on the Mac said it only support developing apps on macOS Catalina 10.15.4, thus the upgrade.

The Visual Studio 2019 version update was over 8GB, but the mac update was only slightly over 3GB.  So like you said, updating everything to the latest/greatest worked!

With these updates, everyone is happy.

Comment: The edit from @Dharman was a good one, please leave it be. The material on Stack Overflow can be thought of as being closer to Wikipedia, and not as much like a chatroom. Keeping material timeless, succinct and neutral is generally preferred here.